# Which API is being used in this website to sign in, and display a profile image?

Tags: api, wordpress, sign

I'm a bit puzzled. [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) has an area for comments, but I noticed that the people who comment, have their own link and profile image. I understand that the author of that site is using Wordpress.

Is this being accomplished with Wordpress or another API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress supports Gravatar, which is essentially a globally recognised avatar.  It uses your email address to match up to a Gravatar profile.  As you, and only you should have that email address, it should match up to a singular Gravatar profile, if you have one.

Comment: but are user signing-in in that website? Where?

Comment: I wouldn imagine when you first enter your details to create a comment, you register an account...

Comment: @jano: No, the users do not need to sign in. When they enter their email address, the site (css-tricks) fetches the gravatar image from gravatar using the (md5 hashed) email address as identifier. See this link for details on how it works: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

Answer (score 1):

Gravatar.com (same as here), it uses the e-mail address.